# Foreach associative array table

Tags: php, associative-array

> **Edit: We got there in the end, Thanks guys! It was the HTML tables confusing me.
>
> ```
>            <tr>
>                <td><?php echo $row['owner_firstname'];?></td>
>                <td><?php echo $row['owner_surname'];}?></td>
>            </tr>**
> ```

I am trying to put some information into a table and I don't want to do it using this method...

```
<tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows[0]['owner_firstname'] ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows[0]['owner_surname'] ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows[0]['owner_contantno'] ; ?></td>
</tr>
```

I want to use a foreach loop but I am struggling to get it working, Each person from the database is [0],[1],[2] etc in my array.

Here is a print_r of my dataset

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => LEI12345
            [owner_firstname] => Shanel
            [owner_surname] => **********
            [owner_contantno] => *******
            [owner_address] => ********
            [band_firstname] => Nathan
            [band_lastname] => **********
            [band_disability] => *******
            [band_emergencycontact] => ********
            [band_description] => ************
        )

)
```

Comment: Please show your code where you are fetching data from the database

Comment: I am using PDO - public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

Comment: Have you actually read the documentation about foreach? This is very basic...

Comment: PLease share the code what you've tried - in your question!

Comment: If you don't want to use this method then what method are you expecting? I'm unable to follow what you're up to.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I understand foreach, I am using array_keys($rows) but it's just returning Array ( [0] => 0 )

Comment: It doesn't feel like you do... `foreach($rows as $row) { echo $row['owner_firstname'] }` or just do a foreach in the first foreach (if you don't want to manually write the column names). The documentation do actually cover this...  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I got it in the end :) It was the HTML table part that was confusing me, But we got there in the end. Thanks guys!

<?php foreach($rows as $row){?>

           <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['owner_firstname'];?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['owner_surname'];}?></td>
           </tr>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = $yourDataSet; // your data set here
// check data
if($data) {
  foreach($data as $val) {
    $str = "";
    $str = "<tr>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $val['owner_firstname'] . "</td>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $val['owner_surname'] . "</td>";
    // add other td here if there's more

    // end of tr
    $str .= "</tr>";
    echo $str;
  }
}
```

try this one, i hope this one would help

Comment: what if query return id and name how to loop throug so the id and name can settle in one <td value = "id">name</td>

Answer (score -1):

from your for each you can grab results like this

get your results to an array

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
foreach($rows as $key=> $row){
    if(is_array($row))
        foreach($row as $id => $val)
            echo  '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
}
```

Comment: It's a multidimensional array so in this example, `$value` is actually an array.

Comment: wrong. will throw an error: array to string convertion.

Comment: sorry for the wrong guide.I have updated the answer.

Comment: what if query return id and name how to loop throug so the id and name can settle in one `<td value = "id">name</td>`